# Page Loads different between page loads

Tags: html, css

My friend owns this site and is making it by hand

http://www.vistavapors.com/

everyone like 5 page reloads the top menu does this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/UG03N.png (in chrome)

i've heavily debugged in chrome's tools and can find no difference in css between when it happens and when it doesn't.

Anyone have a clue?

Comment: What's the problem? White words not align with blue words?

Comment: I don't get it, on my Chromium page looks exactly like on screenshot provided **every** time. Is scrolling text supposed to be aligned with static one?

Comment: yes, randomly the white words do not align with blue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works in Firefox:

```
#head-main span
{
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

but @cvsguimaraes version doesn't work

Comment: I had to also cover the text in a div with display:inline .. moral of the story don't ever have free floating text

Answer (score 0):

If you talking about the vertical alignment between the white and blue words at top, you just need to change the vertical alignment of the `<li>` to match the `<span>` vertical alignment .

```
#head-main ul
{
  vertical-align:top;
}
```